# Numpy: Read csv, deal with undefined values

Tags: python, csv, numpy

What is the best way to read data from a csv file into a numpy array when some of the values are labelled as 'undefined' as follows:

```
0.231620,0.00001,444.157
0.225370,--undefined--,1914.637
0.237870,0.0003,--undefined--
```

I have a lot of these files that I will have to loop over, and it is fine to assume that an undefined value should be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Pandas, just use Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', dtype=np.float, delimiter=',',
    missing_values='--undefined--', filling_values=0.0,
    )
```

Comment: Lots of good answers. I had settled on Marcus Renno's using Pandas, and that works great. But this one is a little bit better for only relying on Numpy (and bonus style points for being a one-liner).

Answer (score 2):

To read CSV files and replace the values the best way I think it is using Pandas which uses numpy as well

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', header=None)
df.replace("--undefined--", 0.0, inplace=True)
df

         0        1         2
0  0.23162  0.00001   444.157
1  0.22537        0  1914.637
2  0.23787   0.0003         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try to cast each value you read to float, then catch typecast ValueError exception and assign it to zero in exception handler.

This will be the most pythonic way

Assuming your CSV contains float values, you should end with something like:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as fd:
    # iterate over all lines in csv
    for line in fd:
        # split and iterate over values in line, maintaining item index
        for i, value in enumerate(line.split(',')):
            try:
                value = float(value)
            except ValueError:
                # consider undefined/non-float value equals to 0
                value = 0.0
            # store parsed value wherever you need it
            print('value[%d] = %f' % (i, value))
```

Alternatively, of only '--undefined--' strings to be handled as '0.0', you can write it like (the innermost loop)

```
            value = float(value) if value != '--undefined--' else 0
```